# Object in strict mode

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an object and I need it to run the content of the page. I need to wrap it with strict mode. I tried to return it to use in global scope, but it didn't solve my issue.

```
(function($) {
   "use strict";

   var MyObj = {
       // some code here.
   }

   return MyObj;

})(jQuery);

console.log(MyObj); // <= undefined
```

How can I access to this object from anywhere of my project?

Comment: Your IIFE returns it to nowhere. Put `var foo = ` before your function definition&execution and use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have there is an [immediately-invoked function expression (IIFE)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) which is specifically designed to keep things separate from the external scope.  Since you're returning `MyObj`, all you have to do to make it available in the global scope is this:

```
var MyObj = (function($) {
    "use strict";

    var MyObj = {
        // some code here.
    }

    return MyObj;

})(jQuery);

console.log(MyObj);
```

The other way to do this would be to put `MyObj` in the global space explicitly.  In a browser, the global object is called `window`, so you could, inside your IIFE, say `window.MyObj = { /* some code here */ }`.  I would discourage this approach, though, because it's not clear to the outside observer that that's happening (i.e., you would have to rely on documentation).  The better approach is to return the objects you want to expose, and the caller can choose to put those in global space.

Answer (score 1):

Using `use strict`, you can only put an Object in int the global namespace explicitly.
For example, you could use `window.myObj = MyObj` in your function.

Another possible way to achieve your goal is by passing the global object to your function (it could be window in the browser or global in nodejs).

```
(function($, global) {
   "use strict";
   var MyObj = {}
   global.myObj = MyObj;
})(jQuery, window);
```

Moreover, as Ethan suggested, since you return MyObj, you could simply assign the result of the invocation to a variable.

```
var myObj = (function($) {
   "use strict";
   var MyObj = {}
   return x
})(jQuery);
myObj; //now defined in the global scope
```

Comment: I like your second example better (passing the global context in), but I still feel like it's a "black box" modifying the global context.  Better, IMO, to have IIFEs return their values (which aren't restricted to a single value, since you can return an object).  This puts the responsibility of global assignment on the caller, where it belongs.

Comment: I absolutely agree with you, Ethan. I think that your answer is the best one, and it describes the approach I usually have in my code.
I just added some different approaches for completeness, but please know that I voted your answer ;-)